# How to create a backup of a Firebase project (Firestore database, cloud functions, security rules, ...)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, database-backups

Periodically, I want to create a backup of my Firebase project.  Mainly a backup of the Firestore database but a backup of the other components (cloud functions, firestore security rules, ...) would also be nice.

Main reason for the backup is to be able to restore the project in case somebody (in)voluntarily messed with the data.

Unfortunately, I don't seem to find an easy way to save (and restore afterwards) a Firebase project.
Suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: You're going to have to write a lot of code to deal with each product individually.  There is no unified backup solution.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for answering (though it was not the answer I was hoping for :-) )  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import (in the linked answer) is a good pointer though!